# How to run TestNG tests parallelly through xml with priority

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a scenario where a class "Pre-Requisite" class have to be executed first and then I have 5 testng classes which have to use certain data gathered from "Pre-Requisite.java" class and execute all 5 classes parallelly. Eg. of an xml below:

```
 <test name="Suite">
            
            <classes>
                <class name="Pre-Requisite"/>  // To be run first
            </test>
        <test name="Suite">        
            <classes>
                <class name="AClass"/>  // To be run in parallel with below classes
                <class name="BClass"/>
                <class name="CClass"/>
                <class name="DClass"/>
                <class name="EClass"/>
            </test>
    </suite>
```

can someone please help me how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the methods in the class "`Pre-Requisite`" with the TestNG annotations - "`@BeforeClass`" or "`@BeforeSuite`", so it will execute the code in the class "`Pre-Requisite`" first.

Then you can execute other classes in parallel through testng.xml, like:

```
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test1" parallel="classes">        
        <classes>
            <class name="AClass"/> 
            <class name="BClass"/>
            <class name="CClass"/>
            <class name="DClass"/>
            <class name="EClass"/>
         </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```